# docker api client/server version mismatch?

Tags: api, docker, docker-api

docker version showing correct api version for both client and server when i run inside python it is throwing error as below.

```html
# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-48.git0fdc778.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      0fdc778/1.12.6
 Built:           Thu Jul 20 00:06:39 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-48.git0fdc778.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      0fdc778/1.12.6
 Built:           Thu Jul 20 00:06:39 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
#
```

But when i run with python it is throwing error as below.

```html
 # python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 29 2016, 10:12:21)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
>>> print client.version()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 177, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("client is newer than server (client API version: 1.30, server API version: 1.24)")
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It says API of your docker python package doesn’t match the docker engine server API. You should install a docker python package compatible with 1.24 or update your docker engine API to 1.30.

Additionally, you can try assigning new value to your docker client as follows:

client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version="1.24")

OR

client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version="1.24")